# AWS CodePipeline execute failed in deploying Nodejs app in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, npm-install, aws-codepipeline

I know its a repetitive question but I didn't see any solution out there.

I deployed Nodejs app in Elastic Beanstalk through AWS CodePipeline. It was running perfect but after AWS announces a newer version of Linux OS, it's health became degraded and the deployment after this will also fail by CodePipeline.

So I decided to upgrade the Linux version but after that, the problem is didn't resolve and it shows me this error.

[image]

I checked eb-engine.log and I came to know that one of the nodejs package is didn't install by NPM.

> 2022/02/06 10:24:24.575676 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution
> of command [app-deploy] - [Use NPM to install dependencies]. Stop
> running the command. Error: Command /bin/sh -c npm --production
> install failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:sharp: Installation
> error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.npm/_libvips' npm WARN
> newbackend@1.0.0 No description npm WARN newbackend@1.0.0 No
> repository field.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! sharp@0.30.0
> install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR!
> Failed at the sharp@0.30.0 install script. npm ERR! This is probably
> not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
> above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /root/.npm/_logs/2022-02-06T10_24_24_562Z-debug.log
>
> 2022/02/06 10:24:24.575682 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic 2022/02/06
> 10:24:24.575792 [INFO] CommandService Response:
> {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine
> execution has encountered an
> error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment: You
> didn't specify a Node.js version in the 'package.json' file in your
> source bundle. The deployment didn't install a specific Node.js
> version.","timestamp":1644143057,"severity":"INFO"},{"msg":"Instance
> deployment: 'npm' failed to install dependencies that you defined in
> 'package.json'. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'. The deployment
> failed.","timestamp":1644143064,"severity":"ERROR"},{"msg":"Instance
> deployment failed. For details, see
> 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1644143064,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}
>
> 2022/02/06 10:24:24.575979 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution
> on command: app-deploy

```
{
  "name": "newbackend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1069.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cryptr": "^6.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "express-validator": "^6.14.0",
    "influx": "^5.9.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.4",
    "sharp": "^0.30.0",
    "validator": "^13.7.0"
  }
}
```

This is my package.json file. It is a simple nodejs app that serves as an API. Now the problem is with the installation of sharp package. If something is missing, please correct me.

I know there is a problem with NPM install but I don't know how to resolve this on AWS CodePipeline.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You have to check the buildspec.yml file and edit it to install the dependencies. Also are the dependencies specified in package.json ?

Comment: Yeah, the dependencies are specified in package.json @error404
But I didn't add buildspec.yml file in my app

Comment: so where are you executing `npm install -g ` command ?

Comment: I really don't know about it. It was working perfectly before without buildspec.yml file. Did I follow the wrong path in deployment? Before I just updated my repo and CodePipeline follows the changes.